# why these fields are mismatching in opensearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

I am working on an Opensearch index and its contains 211 fields but on Opensearch discover page its only shows 80 fields I don't know why can anyone help me to solve this issue. in opensearch.

Comment: Do all 211 fields contains at least one value?

Comment: Numbers that you are seeing can be limited due to `Kibana index pattern setting`, `Data Volume`, `Field Mapping`. Try to check each, could help to find which one is causing the issue.